# Why is dd randomly throwing a "No space left on device" error even though there is plenty?

Tags: linux, dd

I am trying to flash an image on a ssd, but have to start multiple attempts until it finally succeeds.

The image is 3 GB in size, the ssd has 1.8 TB. I've seen other people have problems with inodes, but that does not seem to be the cause here. All the information should be in these logs:

```
$ ls -lah raspios_out.img 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3,0G Jun 20 19:02 raspios_out.img

$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   40G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 39,5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0  1,8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  256M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0  1,8T  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1 50,6M  0 rom  

$ ls -la /dev/sdb*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Jun 20 19:27 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Jun 20 19:25 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 18 Jun 20 19:25 /dev/sdb2

$ df -i
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            227699     504  227195    1% /dev
tmpfs           251397     763  250634    1% /run
/dev/sda5      2588672  852421 1736251   33% /
tmpfs           251397       1  251396    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           251397       5  251392    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           251397      19  251378    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1            0       0       0     - /boot/efi
AustauschVM       1000 -999000 1000000     - /media/austauschVM2
tmpfs           251397      36  251361    1% /run/user/1000
none            251397       7  251390    1% /run/qemu

$ dd --version
dd (coreutils) 8.30
[...]

$ uname -a
Linux falste-linux-vm 5.15.0-75-generic #82~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 7 19:37:37 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo dd bs=1M if=raspios_out.img of=/dev/sdb conv=fdatasync  status=progress
1045430272 bytes (1,0 GB, 997 MiB) copied, 115 s, 9,1 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
1095+0 records in
1094+0 records out
1147142144 bytes (1,1 GB, 1,1 GiB) copied, 114,823 s, 10,0 MB/s

$ sudo dd bs=1M if=raspios_out.img of=/dev/sdb conv=fdatasync  status=progress
702545920 bytes (703 MB, 670 MiB) copied, 79 s, 8,9 MB/s 
dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
698+0 records in
697+0 records out
730857472 bytes (731 MB, 697 MiB) copied, 79,0955 s, 9,2 MB/s

$ sudo dd bs=1M if=raspios_out.img of=/dev/sdb conv=fdatasync  status=progress
1944059904 bytes (1,9 GB, 1,8 GiB) copied, 205 s, 9,5 MB/s 
dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
1855+0 records in
1854+0 records out
1944059904 bytes (1,9 GB, 1,8 GiB) copied, 204,887 s, 9,5 MB/s

$ sudo dd bs=1M if=raspios_out.img of=/dev/sdb conv=fdatasync  status=progress
343932928 bytes (344 MB, 328 MiB) copied, 41 s, 8,3 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
355+0 records in
354+0 records out
371195904 bytes (371 MB, 354 MiB) copied, 41,5655 s, 8,9 MB/s

[...]
```

Once I also got this error, although I am more concerned about the other one:

```
dd: fdatasync failed for '/dev/sdb': Input/output error
```

What I tried:

- Restarting the VM
- Unplugging and replugging the SSD
- Different `bs` parameter settings
- Running the command multiple times

I don't think any of those had any impact on the issue.

What could cause this?

Comment: Does `cat raspios_out.img > /dev/sdb` throw an error? Oftentimes `dd` really is not necessary when writing to a raw device. You also mention remounting the ssd but I hope you do not have it mounted during the copy.

Comment: `$ sudo cat raspios_out.img > /dev/sdb` leads to `bash: /dev/sdb: Permission denied`. No it's not mounted, I meant the usb device is passed through to the VM. It's an external ssd. `$ cat /proc/mounts | grep sdb` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `sdb` is correct and your image is for a full disk, this will work:

```
sudo -s    # Enter your password if prompted
cat raspios_out.img >/dev/sdb 
sync
```

What I'm seeing from my interpretation of your logs, though, is that `sdb` is the wrong device as it only has around 2GB space available

Comment: That worked, thank you. I think you misread the space on sdb, it's 2 TB not 2 GB. Why does this work, though? What is the difference to using dd and why is dd usually recommended when flashing images then?

Comment: @falste `dd` definitely has its uses. But for a straight copy either `cat` or `pv` is not really any slower and if you get the flags wrong for `dd` (it use its default settings) they will be significantly faster